# how to set a text of a textview from another activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-inflate

I am inflating a layout in the viewpager of the current activity but I need to set the textview text of this layout so that I can inflate it and it displays the new text I am doing :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.content);
txt.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Content")));
```

but that's getting me a nullpointerexception, how can I solve this how can I set the text of the textview of a layout that I am not in which mean from outside this layout..

Comment: Please show your logcat. May be you want to save the 'Content' in sharedprefrences and use it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change - `TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.content);`

to

`TextView txt=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.content);`

Comment: @Shruti - didn't get it

Answer (score 1):

To find the textView you want you must specify the parentView 
and so

```
TextView txt=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.content);
```